# how to change int in a viewbag in MSVWD2010 Express c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Not sure if I am asking this correctly.

I have a @Viewbag.Items in which i want to case. ie 
when 7 then 'blah' or when '8' then 'blah2'

this is a int which i want to change to a char. Like a Case When in MSSQL

```
 @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.Items)
    {
       <tr> 
            <td>@item.Item_Id</td>
            <td>@item.NAME</td>
            <td>@item.DOCUMENTSTATUS</td>
       </tr>
```

the int can be either 1,7,8 or null

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "switch"?

Say your controller is something like this maybe?

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    int?[] values = new int?[] { 1, 7, 8, null };
    ViewBag.Items = values;

    return View();
}
```

And your view, you could switch (like sql case) to change to some other values.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Items) {
        <tr>
            @switch (item as int?) {
                case 1:
                <td>I'm 1</td>
                    break;
                case 7:
                <td>I'm 7</td>
                    break;
                case 8:
                <td>I'm 8</td>
                    break;
                case null:
                <td>I'm null</td>
                    break;
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```